# MP4 and AAC file extensions

Tags: macos

I may have realized that users can easily can create a protected file extension.
The first two that exist are AAC and MP4.

Some questions:

1. How did they create those protected file extensions?
2. What programming language is that done in?
3. Can users burn those protected file extensions; whereas, they cannot rip them from optical medium afterwards?
4. Why did Apple developers stopped using the protected versions of those file formats?
5. How can I revert those file formats to protected?

Comment: This is not a programming-related question.  Please try on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

MP4 (MPEG 4) is an audio/video container format, and AAC is an audio codec. Neither one is inherently "protected" in any sense, and there is a lot more to them than just a file extension.

Apple iTunes used to store downloaded music in an MPEG4 container using [FairPlay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FairPlay#EMI_music_made_available_DRM-free) encryption, which was customarily distributed using the `.m4p` extension (contrast with the standard `.m4a` for MPEG4 audio). These files could be played and burned to CD without restrictions, but could not be played on a computer or other device by users other than the owner. However, as they are no longer required to do so by record labels, they phased out this encryption between 2007 and 2009. There is no supported method for creating FairPlay-encrypted files yourself.